# Get current (logged) user in ASP.NET Core 3.0 .razor page

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm testing the waters with a blazer server-side app and trying to get the logged user in a .razor page. This

```
UserManager.GetUserAsync(User)
```

works in .cshtml view, but I cannot find a way to get it to work in .razor page. There is no "User" property to access. I use the IdentityUser with my ApplicationUser model that extends IdentityUser. I'm using AspNetCore 3.0 Preview 6.

Comment: hey, can you reject my answer and accept the chris answer below please

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you surround your code with the `AuthorizeView` component you can get access to a `context` object that supplies the current user.

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <h1>Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name!</h1>
        <p>You can only see this content if you're authenticated.</p>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <h1>Authentication Failure!</h1>
        <p>You're not signed in.</p>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

If you don't want to use that approach you can request a cascading parameter called `authenticationStateTask`, which is provided by the `CascadingAuthenticationState`.

```
@page "/"

<button @onclick="@LogUsername">Log username</button>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }

    private async Task LogUsername()
    {
        var authState = await authenticationStateTask;
        var user = authState.User;

        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{user.Identity.Name} is authenticated.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The user is NOT authenticated.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

What I did:

1. added this to *Startup.ConfigureServices*

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

2. used this to get the username in my .razor page, these 2 lines first

```
@inject UserManager<WebPageUser> UserManager
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
```

3. then the call to show the username like this:

```
<p>Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User)</p>
```

Comment: I had situation where I have a blazor app using authorized view.. But also had a controller which needed the current user.. This works for that

Comment: Unfortunately, it is strongly recommended that you do not use the IHttpContextAccessor class at all, it is no longer supported in Blazor server and will not work in all cases. [(official warning)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-5.0#blazor-and-shared-state-1)

Answer (score 1):

this one works for Razor page .cshtml

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using [yourproject].Areas.Identity.Data

@inject UserManager<NassPayUser> UserManager

@{
var currentuser=UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result;
}
```

if you want to get current user in .cs you can use the folowing.

```
private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
public constucturModel(UserManager<AppUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }
```

now you can reach any user you want by

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
```

or just loop through

```
var users = _userManager.Users;
```

Comment: What do you need in Program.cs do use this?